# Update Table with DateDiff without using Cursors

Tags: sql, t-sql

Hoping someone could help, feel like I made this procedure take much longer than necessary. Trying to update a column for each row based on other rows for the same ID. Currently have a cursor to loop through each VisitorID, then a second cursor to go through each DepartmentID for the current VisitorID and storing the DateDiff for DaysBetweenVisits in a temp table to later update our actual table.

| VisitorID (int) | DepartmentID (int) | VisitDate (datetime) | DaysBetweenVisits (int) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 12-09-2022 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 12-11-2022 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 12-18-2022 | 9 |
| 1 | 2 | 12-28-2022 | 17 |

The procedure works, but it takes way too long to loop through every single record. I'm going to need to do similar procedures later for other fields with similar logic (determine a value for a row based on different/previous rows) which makes me wonder if I missed something obvious to somehow make this all work with a sub-query somehow.

Procedure logic

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

create table #VisitDetails
(
DeptID int,
VisitDate date,
DaysBetween int
);

DECLARE @CurrentVisitor bigint;
DECLARE @CurrentDeptID int;
DECLARE @CurrentDate date;
DECLARE @PrevDeptID int;
DECLARE @PrevDate date;
DECLARE @DaysBetween int;

DECLARE Visitor_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT distinct VisitorID
from [dbo].[visits]
;

OPEN Visitor_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM Visitor_cursor INTO  @CurrentVisitor;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
    
    Truncate table #VisitDetails;

    INSERT INTO #VisitDetails (DeptID, VisitDate, DaysBetween)
    SELECT DeptID, VisitDate, 0
    FROM [dbo].[visits] v
    where v.VisitorID = @CurrentVisitor
    order by DeptID, VisitDate;

    set @CurrentDate = '1900-01-01';
    set @PrevDate = '1900-01-01';
    set @DaysBetween = 0;
    set @PrevDeptID = null

    DECLARE DeptID_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT distinct DeptID, VisitDate
    from #VisitDetails;

    OPEN DeptID_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM DeptID_cursor into @CurrentDeptID, @CurrentDate;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN --DeptID
        if @PrevDeptID is not null and @PrevDeptID <> @CurrentDeptID
            set @PrevDate = '1900-01-01'
        
        If @PrevDate = '1900-01-01'
            set @DaysBetween = 0;
        else if @PrevDate is null
            set @DaysBetween = null;
        else
            set @DaysBetween = DATEDIFF(d, @PrevDate, @CurrentDate);

        UPDATE #VisitDetails
        SET DaysBetween = @DaysBetween
        where DeptID = @CurrentDeptID
        and VisitDate = @CurrentDate;

        set @PrevDeptID = @CurrentDeptID;
        set @PrevDate = @CurrentDate;

        --DECLARE @temptable XML = (SELECT * FROM #VisitDetails FOR XML AUTO)

        FETCH NEXT FROM DeptID_cursor into @CurrentDeptID, @CurrentDate;
    END

    UPDATE v
    set v.DaysBetween = t.DaysBetween
    from visits v
    join #VisitDetails t on v.DeptID = t.DeptID and v.VisitDate = t.VisitDate
    where v.VisitorID = @CurrentVisitor
    ;

    close DeptID_cursor;
    deallocate DeptID_cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM Visitor_cursor INTO  @CurrentVisitor;
END

CLOSE Visitor_cursor;
DEALLOCATE Visitor_cursor;
```

Comment: What is the logic? Describing the code doesn't really help. As for *calculating* the difference, you can easily do that in a `SELECT` using the `LAG` function, eg `LAG(VisitDate) OVER (PARTITION BY VisitorID, Department ID ORDER BY VisitDate DESC)`.

Comment: typically you would join the table to itself on VisitorID and DepartmentID (give the same table diff aliases) then use MIN and MAX of VisitDate and DATEDIFF.  the prob is that only works with 2 visits.  it doesnt work with 3 or more.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos updated with the procedure code. I'll look into the LAG function, seems like it should help, thanks.

Comment: SQL is a set-based language.  You don't loop over your rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning your explanation into DDL/DML (its really helpful if you provide this with the question).

```
DECLARE @Visits TABLE (VisitorID BIGINT, DepartmentID INT, VisitDate DATETIME, DaysBetweenVisits INT);
INSERT INTO @Visits (VisitorID, DepartmentID, VisitDate) VALUES
(1, 1, '12-09-2022'), (1, 2, '12-11-2022'),
(1, 1, '12-18-2022'), (1, 2, '12-28-2022');
```

To get what you're looking for as a set based operation, we can use the windowed function `LAG`. We're using two of the arguments: the column and the number of rows back to go. It uses an `OVER` clause to describe the window, in this case partition (grouped) by VisitorID and DepartmentID and ordered by VisitDate. We can then calculate the date difference in days between the previous row's VisitDate and the current row's VisitDate.

```
SELECT VisitorID, DepartmentID, VisitDate, COALESCE(DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(v.VisitDate,1) OVER (PARTITION BY v.VisitorID, v.DepartmentID ORDER BY v.VisitDate),v.VisitDate),0) AS DaysBetweenVisits
  FROM @Visits v
```

| VisitorID | DepartmentID | VisitDate | DaysBetweenVisits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-12-09 00:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-12-18 00:00:00.000 | 9 |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-12-11 00:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-12-28 00:00:00.000 | 17 |

Using Windowed functions with an update can be a little tricky, and you need to use a subquery:

```
UPDATE v
   SET DaysBetweenVisits = DaysBetween
  FROM (
        SELECT VisitorID, DepartmentID, COALESCE(DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(v.VisitDate,1) OVER (PARTITION BY v.VisitorID, v.DepartmentID ORDER BY v.VisitDate),v.VisitDate),0) AS DaysBetween, DaysBetweenVisits 
          FROM @Visits v
       ) v
```